# Excel Concat based on Cell's last value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a concatenation function, which looks at the prefix, and based on the value, attaches the suffix, based on the conversion shown on the right of the data. Currently using this
`=CONCAT($J19443,(IF(LEFT(TRIM(K19443),1)="1","1","false")))`, but with OR's it can be quite hard

[image: This is the sample Data]

Comment: You have a lookup table so I'd go with `VLOOKUP`

Comment: That is true, but I have to do this for 100's of files, so rather have a formula instead of a table.

Comment: Then use `CHOOSE` if these are 15 possibilities. Or even a simple if to check against Value.

Comment: How would I implement that here?

Comment: Maybe even like: `=A$2&IF(B2<10,B2,IF(B2<15,CHAR(B2+58),"I"))` where `ABC` is in `A2`. Be creative with `IF`, `CHOOSE`, `CHAR` etc. if you don't have an actual lookup table.